# How to deal with: ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard

Tags: python, opencv, error-handling

I have a MacBook Pro on which I installed VirtualBox, installed Anaconda (from https://www.continuum.io), and installed OpenCV (`conda install -c menpo opencv`)

Executed Python:

```
python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
```

and tried to import OpenCV:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard
```

I Googled the error, but there are not many entries about that, and the ones I found were unsolved. I do not understand even what is the error about, so no clue how to solve it. I have installed Anaconda and OpenCV many times on other systems without problems.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: strange. This could mean that glib could be missing. Can you try installing that? conda install -c anaconda glib

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, I checked that, and update the lib is OK.

Use the command `conda install -c anaconda glib`.

Answer (score 6):

In [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) it seems that problem is opposite to what [VamsidharReddyGaddam was supposing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177330/how-to-deal-with-importerror-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libatk-1-0-so-0-undefi#comment87383772_50177330).

I checked:

```
grep -l g_log_structured_standard /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*glib*.so*

# And

grep -l g_log_structured_standard ~/anaconda3/lib/*glib*so*
```

And the first `find` was successful and the second not.

I suppose that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0` is compiled/linked against a newer `libglib` (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.1` on Ubuntu 18.04) than the one which is installed by Anaconda (`~/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.5306.0` at the moment).

So a different **dirty** hack could "help":

```
mv ~/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 ~/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.backup
```

in Ubuntu 18.04. :/ (I am suspicious that it could bring different problems later!!!)

How could we file an issue at Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I realized my [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) was running on Python 3.7 and the Python program it was referring to was in the Anaconda folder.

I switched to the system-wide Python interpreter running version 3.9 and it worked for me. See if it works for you too.