# SWIG Linker: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv8fastFreeEPv (cv::fastFree(void*))

Tags: python, c++, opencv, swig

I'm having some trouble getting my SWIG wrapper to work in python after I changed some code. I suspect it has to do with the linker.

My question concerns [this github](https://github.com/jlowenz/pyviso2):
This file compiles as described in the readme, and can be imported without issues in python.

I have made some changes to the code that require OpenCV. When building in C++, no errors occur and the code runs as expected, after the CMakeLists file was modified to also add some OpenCV libraries.

After I made these modifications, I once again want to SWIG this to python, but I'm getting many linker errors. After googling I have already added the following arguments to the SWIG setup.py which you can find [here](https://github.com/jlowenz/pyviso2/blob/master/src/setup.py)

```
extra_compile_args=['-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_features2d 
                     -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core','-msse3'],

include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(), 
              '/usr/local/include/opencv',
              '/usr/local/include'])])
```

Which should add the correct include / library folders as well as the used libs (xfeatures, core, ..) in the correct order. An example of one of the files is :

```
gcc -pthread -B /home/floris/Software/Anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/floris/Software/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -I/home/floris/Software/Anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c filter.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/filter.o -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -msse3
```

The order was found by issuing the

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

command, and taking the required libraries in the same order.

In the end, the SWIG command yields no errors. When loading the supposedly generated viso2 module in python (after adding the location of the module to the sys.path), it yields error:

```
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv8fastFreeEPv
```

which can be c++filt to become cv::fastFree(void*)

When running

```
ldd -r _viso2......linux.so
```

Quite a big list of undefined symbols show up.

```
<floris@OPTIMUSPRIME:/magatank/DataSets/LibViso2_python/pyviso2_gitclone/src$ ldd -r _viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdfd7bc000)
    libstdc++.so.6 =&gt; /home/floris/Software/Anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4c7b3d0000)
    libm.so.6 =&gt; /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4c7b032000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 =&gt; /home/floris/Software/Anaconda3/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4c7ae20000)
    libpthread.so.0 =&gt; /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4c7ac01000)
    libc.so.6 =&gt; /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4c7a810000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4c7b9c1000)
undefined symbol: PyExc_ValueError  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyBool_Type   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_IndexError  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_SyntaxError (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyCapsule_Type    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PySlice_Type  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _Py_NoneStruct    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_AttributeError  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_IOError (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_MemoryError (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyType_Type   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_OverflowError   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_ZeroDivisionError   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_NotImplementedError (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_RuntimeError    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _Py_NotImplementedStruct  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_StopIteration   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_TypeError   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_GenericGetAttr   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyFloat_Type  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_SystemError (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_ImportError (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyTuple_SetItem   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_AsLong (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv8fastFreeEPv    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_GetAttr  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyImport_AddModule    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_Call (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_Init (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyInstanceMethod_New  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_Str  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_GetAttrString    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Restore (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyType_IsSubtype  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyModule_GetDict  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyModule_AddObject    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv7noArrayEv  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyTuple_New   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_SetAttr  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_IsInstance   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyEval_RestoreThread  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv11xfeatures2d4SIFT6createEiiddd (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyDict_SetItemString  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyUnicode_FromFormat  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_AsDouble   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_SetObject   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _PyObject_New (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Format  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyFloat_FromDouble    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyFloat_AsDouble  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyImport_ImportModule (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyUnicode_FromString  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PySequence_Check  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv5errorEiRKNS_6StringEPKcS4_i    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Clear   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6String8allocateEm  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: Py_DecRef (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyCapsule_Import  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_FromVoidPtr    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_SetString   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyEval_InitThreads    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyCapsule_New (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyArg_ParseTuple  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3MatC1ERKS0_RKNS_5Rect_IiEE (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyGILState_Release    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyCapsule_GetPointer  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_Free (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyType_Ready  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_Size (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyEval_SaveThread (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PySequence_GetItem    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PySequence_Size   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_FromLong   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_WriteUnraisable (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_IsTrue   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyModule_Create2  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat20updateContinuityFlagEv    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Occurred    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Fetch   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PySlice_GetIndices    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyCallable_Check  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_FromUnsignedLong   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyArg_UnpackTuple (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyGILState_Ensure (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_Malloc   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Print   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyUnicode_Concat  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZNK2cv3Mat6copyToERKNS_12_OutputArrayE   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3MatC1ERKS0_RKNS_5RangeES5_ (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv  (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyUnicode_AsUTF8String    (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyBytes_AsStringAndSize   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyBool_FromLong   (./_viso2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

The only functionality I added is the OpenCV functionality.

Thanks for reading. If you have an idea let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: Those need to be arguments to the linker, not the compiler. I'm not sure if `extra_compile_args` are passed to the linker but you should check it out.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I have edited the question so it includes an example for one of the files, "filter.cpp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass libraries and library-paths to the build-process by using arguments `libraries` and `library_dirs`, i.e.:

```
ext = Extension(....
                libraries=["opencv_xfeatures2d", "opencv_features2d", 
                           "opencv_highgui", "opencv_core"],
                library_dirs=['/usr/local/lib']
                )
```

Note, that `-l` and `-L` are not needed - they are taken care of by distutils.

Why didn't adding them to extra compile flags work?

Building extension consist of following steps:

1. building first cpp-file, creates an object-file. Uses **compiler** flags.
2. building further cpp-files (if there are some). Uses **compiler** flags.
3. links all object files together, needs libraries. Uses **linker** flags.

As you can see, libraries are needed in the last step, but they are not provided, because they were part of compiler-flags. On the other hand the libraries are provided during the compilation, but not needed at this stage.

Comment: Very clear answer, thank you. After looking further into [the distutils.core.Extension](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html) I also found an example of this. I had a minor problem due to Ubuntu 18.04 after this related to glib but this was easily solved by performing a conda update as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177330/how-to-deal-with-importerror-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libatk-1-0-so-0-undefi/50620062#50620062)